# NPM testing errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

Is there any known errors with npm on Ubuntu 18.04? Or 100:1 error known fix?

I am trying to complete a course and I need to be able to test the code with npm test.

I have tried deleting it and reinstalling several times, it doesn't help.

The homework.js file is committed to my github. I have confirmed all the files are present.

[image: 100:1 Parsing error]

Comment: It seems like homework.js contains some bugs, check for it in the javascript code itself. 100:1 is the number of line where the bug exists.

Comment: extremely helpful! this is my first time using npm testing so I was able to find the issue with your tip. thank you!

Comment: You're most welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great. I was finally able to fix it!

it was my homework.js file all along.

looks it was working as intended (first time user here)

I completed the file with correct answers (expected results)

then, i had a jest issue that was fixed with

`yarn add --dev jest`

Now, all tests have passed!